How do I find which file on an APFS disk is associated with a specific `doc-id` and/or `file-id` in macOS?
I am on macOS 14.5 with APFS formatted SSD. Disk Utility always reports the same error:

error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 1341220, file-id 8567077 but no inode references this doc-id.

I have a few of these and they show up on every single snapshot created. I really don't want to have to format and restore from Time Machine backup.
I am assuming that once I find the file(s) associated associated with these errors that I can delete it and all will be hunky-dory in the world again.
So… How do I find which file in my file system is associated with the doc-id/file-id in question?

IMO, if there is no inode, then there is no file to be found.

@DavidAnderson – Then how would I correct the doc-id tree?
